# From measure $P_X$ and knowing that $P_X=\int f_X d\mu$, how to find $f_X$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If we know that $P_X=\int f_X \ d\mu$, where $\mu$ is another measure(could be lebesgue) and I know what I get from $P_X(B), \ \forall B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, how can I deduce the function $f_X$?
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Some comments have suggested $\frac{d P_X(]-\infty,x])}{dx}=f(x)$, using the fundamental theorem of calculus. However, the only version I know is the following:

If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ is integrable, and the function $F$ given by $F(x)=\int^x_a f \ dm$ is differentiable for $x \in (a,b)$ with derivative $F'=f$. The measure $m$ is Lebesgue.

We usually define $F(x)=P_X(]-\infty,x])$. So, what changes do we need to do to the text of the above theorem to be able to apply it to the case  $F(x)=P_X(]-\infty,x])$?

Comment: By $P_X(B)$, do you mean $\int_Bf_Xd\mu$?

Comment: @MichaelM. Yes, I do.

Comment: $$f_X(x)=\frac{d}{dx}P_X((-\infty,x])$$

Comment: @Did, I thought that theorem was only valid when $P_X((-\infty,x])=P_X([a,x])$. The way it's written in the notes/textbook I'm using is that $F(x)=\int_a^xf_X \ d \mu$ 
Thanks for the helpful comment

Comment: The general definition of the CDF $F_X$ of a random variable $X$ with PDF $f_X$ shows that $$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(t)dt,$$ and I have no idea why your text pretends otherwise.

Comment: In the notes/textbook that you are using, is $\mu$ Lebesgue measure or something else?

Comment: @Did, I think it has to do with the stating of the fundamental theorem of calculus... for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255047/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-for-lebesgue-integral

Is there a more general version of this theorem? Thanks

Comment: @JohnDawkins is for lebesgue, but I'm also interested(my curiosity) in a more general setting.

Comment: @Did I think I misread, or wrote unclearly something. I've edited my question. Could you still help me?

Comment: If the $-\infty$ bound annoys you, fix some $a$ and note that, for every $x$, $$F(x)=c+\int_a^xf(t)dt,\qquad\text{with}\ c=\int_{-\infty}^af(t)dt.$$

Comment: @Did Thanks. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Formally you can use

$$
f(x) = \mathsf{E}[ \delta(X-x)]
$$

where $X$ is the random variable, $x$ the values it can attain, and $\mathsf{E}$ the expectation value. Alternatively you can compute the cdf:

$$
cdf(x) = \mathrm{Prob}(X < x) = \mathsf{E}[ \theta(x-X)]
$$

where $\theta$ is the Heaviside function. You can then obtain $f(x)$ by differentiating the $cdf$.

Comment: Why point to difficult-to-master physicists "definitions" when it is so simple to write down the true definitions?

Comment: This could open up a long discussion. Dirac deltas have been used long before "their true definition" (whatever that means) was given. I believe that the  difficult-to-master physicists "definitions" is actually very illuminating (and this was OP's question). Moreover you know very well that what I wrote can be perfectly made sense of.

Comment: @Did  In any case I started my answer with the disclaimer "formally". The second part of my answer is the same as yours.

Comment: "True definition" means "mathematically rigorous definition", there is no mystery involved. Of course "what (you) wrote can be perfectly made sense of", unfortunately this fact is perfectly offtopic here.

Comment: @Did I beg to disagree. The mistake (if of mistake you want to speak) is  notational. Let me make an example. In countless of posts here (and research papers) the Fourier transform is written as an integral even when the "true" definition is actually something else (and may involve limits, tests functions etc.). But it is just much simpler to write it as an integral (and also often more helpful from a computational point of view). In any case I take your point.

Comment: @Did Lastly: even "your" answer via "differentiation" is only correct in those circumstances where standard differentiation makes sense, otherwise a more general definition of differentiation is needed. You are using a notation too.

Comment: Do you see "mistake" in what I wrote? Of course, the differentiation answer  needs qualification (but no "more general definition of differentiation", to be precise, the formula in my comment defines the PDF almost everywhere) but, to conflate this with the prerequisites necessary to even make sense of the Dirac answer is misleading: simple precautions to be added in one case, whole conceptual framework to explain in the other.